# How to create options from 1 to 100 in selection list by using javascript?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, html-select

I want to create options 1 to 100 by using looping in java script and this is my html code:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Quantity</td>
    <td><select id="quantiti"></select></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is my java script:

```
function quantity(){
    var select = document.getElementById('quantiti');
    for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
    select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(i+1, i);
  }
}
```

```js
function quantity() {
  var select = document.getElementById('quantiti');
  for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(i + 1, i);
  }
}

window.onload = quantity;
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Quantity</td>
    <td><select id="quantiti"></select></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I check so many times and I still could not find anything wrong with my code.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: When is your function `quantity()`called?

Comment: Your code is working https://jsfiddle.net/gaeLLx07/! Looks like you are not calling function

Comment: Adding your code as a runanble snippet with zero changes shows that it creates 100 options, as expected. The text values are a little off, but that is easily fixed. Or did you forget to call *quantity*?

Comment: Ya, I have no idea I need to do that. However, the code is not working again after I put into external js. file, why? I can sure the file is linked.
This is my file https://jsfiddle.net/3t0c6fbd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the function in somewhere, you only defined the function but is not executed.

I checked your code, but if you start the value from 1 `var i = 1`, this will start from 2 when is executed, because you are adding +1 when start.

Also if you set the limit to 100 (`i <= 100`) will give you 101 at the end (because is adding +1 when finish)

The correct way is this: (also i added custom amount to set)

```
function quantity(amount){
  var select = document.getElementById('quantiti');
  for (var i = 0; i < amount; i++){
      select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(i+1, i);
    }
}

quantity(100);
```

Test here: https://jsfiddle.net/ztsaa667/1/

Comment: Thanks, but one more question, can the function name same as id name?

Comment: yes, you can set any name to the function, just change `function quantity(amount)` to something like `function HelloWorld(amount)` and change too when is executed `quantity(100);` to `HelloWorld(100);`

Answer (score 2):

```
function quantity(){
    var select = document.getElementById('quantiti');
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(i+1, i);
  }
}
quantity();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k0xsy15q/

You forgot to call quantity(), also corrected the select options range.

Comment: So weird, it only working when I put inside HTML and it's not working after put into external js. file. But I can sure that the file already linked. Do you know why?

Comment: This is my file: https://jsfiddle.net/3t0c6fbd/1/
First function is to convert degree F to degree C.

Comment: Don't see why it wouldn't work.. in this version it does: https://jsfiddle.net/3t0c6fbd/2/
Also, you can't add script tags without url's in jsfiddle like these tho: 
    <script src="tempScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Answer (score 1):

Please find the below code i have tested in jsfiddle

```
function quantity(){
    var select = document.getElementById('quantiti');
    for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i++){
    select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(i+1, i);
  }
}
quantity()
```

Comment: Code-only answers aren't very helpful. You should explain why the OP has their issue and how your code fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var options = ""
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
    options += '<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>';
}
document.getElementById('quantiti').innerHTML = options;
```

Answer (score -1):

Easy way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        $('#quantiti').append("<option value="+ i +">"+ i +"</option>");                    
    }
});
```

Comment: There is no jQuery tag, nor is it used in the OP.

Comment: @RobG Written function is not called, that's why i shown in ready function with simple jQuery